# How select columns, where the first row equals TRUE in R?

Tags: r

I am using following code

```
summary.out$which[which.max(summary.out$adjr2),]
```

This gives me column names with one one row, which equals to TRUE or FALSE.
What should I add to this code in order to get column names, where the first row shows TRUE?
Additionally, how can I create that all column names of this output are in one string deliminated with "+" sign? (one string showing "Column1"+"Column2"+"Column3"

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the OP did not provide a minimal reproducible example, we'll assume that `summary.out` is a data frame, and therefore we can use the `colnames()` function to extract the column names once we know which elements of the first row have the value `TRUE`.

Here is a reproducible example illustrating how to use TRUE / FALSE values in the first row of data frame to extract its column names.

```
textData <- "v1,v2,v3,v4
TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE
FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE
TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE"

data <- read.csv(text=textData)

# select column names where first row = TRUE
colnames(data)[data[1,]==TRUE]
```

The preceding line of code uses the `[` form of the extract operator to extract the required elements from the result of the `colnames()` function.

...and the output:

```
> colnames(data)[data[1,]==TRUE]
[1] "v1" "v3" "v4"
```

We can print the names as a single object separated by `+` signs with the `paste()` function and its `collapse =`  argument.

```
# separated by + sign
paste(colnames(data)[data[1,]==TRUE],collapse = " + ")
```

...and the output:

```
> # separated by + sign
> paste(colnames(data)[data[1,]==TRUE],collapse = " + ")
[1] "v1 + v3 + v4"
```